# jquery - Getting DIV id value from an append infinite scrolling

Tags: jquery, ajax, infinite-scroll

I am sorry is there is already solutions for this but I have been looking at a ton here on stack overflow and I can't seem to get a solution for my issue.

I am creating a infinite scrolling option for my site.

I am appending data from a ajax call which returns the html and adds it to a `div` I called `<div class="append"></div>`

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var last_id = $('#last_id').attr('value');
    if (!last_id) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "includes/getmorefirst.php?",
            success: function(data) {
                $( ".append" ).append(data).trigger("append");
            }
        });
    };

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
            $(function() {
                $(".getmoremovies").live("append",function() {
                    var last_id = $(this).attr("id");
                });
            });
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "includes/getmore.php?",
                data: "last_id="+ last_id,
                success: function(data) {
                $( ".append" ).append(data).trigger("append");
            }
            });
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

The HTML returned from this call is

```
<div class="append">
    <div class="divRow">
        <div class="divCell">date here</div>
    </div>
    <div id="20" style="display:none" class="getmoremovies"></div>
</div>
```

The first part of the `AJAX` simply loads the initial 20 records onto the page which then returns `<div id="20" style="display:none" class="getmoremovies"></div>` so the next part of the `AJAX` call can continue the appending.

`id=20` of that div is the last record that was returned so I know where to start the next time when it loads the next 20 and so on.

The problem I am having is trying to get the `id` `attr` of the div `<div id="20" style="display:none" class="getmoremovies"></div>` I need to get that number so I can pass it again through the `AJAX` call.

I am applying a `.trigger("append")` to the actual `append` so this part of the code can get that new value

```
$(function() {
    $(".getmoremovies").live("append",function() {
        var last_id = $(this).attr("id");
    });
});
```

Basically I need to get the `last_id` attr so I can pass it again.

Hope this makes sense

Comment: Better to use a javascript variable and stored last id in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, maybe this is the solution:

```
return $('.getmoremovies').last().attr('id');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w8Lgjqsb/